# root of a unit in a real biquadratic field

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ two  primes numbers $\equiv 1\pmod 4$. If we note by $\varepsilon_m$ the fundamental unit of real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt m)$,  then how can be solved in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{p_1p_2})$ the following equation:
\begin{equation*}
    \varepsilon_{2}\varepsilon_{p_1p_2}\varepsilon_{2p_1p_2}=X^2
\end{equation*}

Comment: MO thread, with an answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92051/root-of-a-unit-in-a-real-biquadratic-field